# How can I improve this breadth-first search in Scala to make it more idomatic FP?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, breadth-first-search

Been looking for a way to do this without a queue, and make it tail-recursive. I'm thinking LazyLists might also help. Would a queue be faster? I'm basically sending mutated state down through each function call with the next level of children.

```
case class Tree [A] (
                      value : A,
                      Right: Option[Tree[A]],
                      Left: Option[Tree[A]]
                    )
object Tree {
  def liftChildren[A](t: Tree[A]) = {
    List(t.Left, t.Right).flatten
  }

  def findChild[A](value: A, t: Tree[A]) : Option[Tree[A]] = {
    var lvl = 0
      def searchChildren(t: List[Tree[A]]): (Option[Tree[A]], List[Tree[A]]) = {
        // could be removed, just for fun
        lvl += 1
        t.foreach(tt => println(s"Scanning Level ${lvl.toString} Value ${tt.value.toString}"))
        //
        val curfind = t.find(tt => {
          tt.value == value
        })
        curfind match {
          case Some(tr) => (Some(tr), t)
          case None => {
            val children: List[Tree[A]] = t.flatMap(tt => Tree.liftChildren(tt))
            children.isEmpty match {
              case true => (None, List.empty)
              case false => searchChildren(children)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    searchChildren(List(t))._1
    }
}

object main extends App {
  println("hello world")
  val tree = Tree[Int](
    1,
    Some(
      Tree[Int](2, None, Some(
        Tree[Int](5,None, Some(Tree[Int](6, None,None))))
      )
    ) ,
    Some(
      Tree[Int](
        3,
        Some(
          Tree[Int](4, None, Some(Tree[Int](7, None,None)))
        ), None
      )
    )
  )
  val res = Tree.findChild(6, tree)
  println("FoundIt" + res)
}
```

It's working as I expect. I'm just wondering whther this could be any better or more idiomatic FP. Would the cats library help at all?

Comment: It looks fine to me. Except for your var lvl that is used for logging, everything else is immutable. So far as I can tell, it is good, functional code.

Comment: Am I using the word lift in liftChildren in a proper way? would that just normally be called lift?

Comment: No, I don't think that's what fp people normally mean by lift. Lifting usually refers to moving a type into some new context, usually some kind of monad. But "liftChildren" is pretty self-explanatory. People will know what you mean when you use lift here.

Comment: Actually, you are correct. You are lifting children into List context. My bad.

Comment: I thought maybe it was right, should i just call it "lift" in that case, you can offer a number of types to lift into, so I'm not sure how'd you separate them.

Comment: I don't think it's worth it to make your lift function flexible enough to accommodate types other than Tree. It will decrease readability for functionality you never use. The way to implement what you want I think is to use higher kinded types. You may want to create another question for it. Luis has already done a great job answering your existing question.

Comment: Actually, to make your lift function generalizable to different types, you will need to provide a parameter that is a function that tells lift how to insert the children into the List context. It seems unnecessary to me. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Ok, understood. Yeah a higher kinded function is beyond the scope of my original question.

Comment: Don't forget to accept Luis's answer! Click the check mark underneath the vote count on the left side of his answer. He worked hard on it, so I think he deserves it. Up to you of course.

Comment: Totally! My first post :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a **tail-recursive** implementation, using **pattern matching**.

```
final case class Tree[+A](value: A, left: Option[Tree[A]], right: Option[Tree[A]])

def find[A](value: A)(tree: Tree[A]): Option[Tree[A]] = {
  import scala.collection.immutable.Queue

  @annotation.tailrec
  def bfs(queue: Queue[Tree[A]]): Option[Tree[A]] =
    queue.dequeueOption match {
      case None => None

      case Some((tree, remaining)) => tree match {
        case Tree(`value`, _, _) => Some(tree)
        case Tree(_, Some(left), Some(right)) => bfs(queue = remaining.enqueue(left).enqueue(right))
        case Tree(_, Some(left), None) => bfs(queue = remaining.enqueue(left))
        case Tree(_, None, Some(right)) => bfs(queue = remaining.enqueue(right))
        case Tree(_, None, None) => bfs(queue = remaining)
      }
    }

  bfs(queue = Queue(tree))
}

def find[A](value: A)(tree: Tree[A]): Option[Tree[A]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def dfs(stack: List[Tree[A]]): Option[Tree[A]] =
    stack match {
      case Nil => None

      case tree :: remaining => tree match {
        case Tree(`value`, _, _) => Some(tree)
        case Tree(_, Some(left), Some(right)) => dfs(stack = left :: right :: remaining)
        case Tree(_, Some(left), None) => dfs(stack = left :: remaining)
        case Tree(_, None, Some(right)) => dfs(stack = right :: remaining)
        case Tree(_, None, None) => dfs(stack = remaining)
      }
    }

  dfs(stack = List(tree))
}
```

---

Here are some implementations using **LazyList**.

```
final case class Tree[+A](value: A, children: List[Tree[A]])

// DFS by right.
def find[A](value: A)(tree: Tree[A]): Option[Tree[A]] =
  LazyList.unfold(List(tree)) {
    case Nil => None
     case tree :: remaining => Some((tree, tree.children reverse_::: remaining))
  }.find(tree => tree.value == value)

// DFS by left.
def find[A](value: A)(tree: Tree[A]): Option[Tree[A]] =
  LazyList.unfold(List(tree)) {
    case Nil => None
    case tree :: remaining => Some((tree, tree.children ::: remaining))
  }.find(tree => tree.value == value)

// BFS
def find[A](value: A)(tree: Tree[A]): Option[Tree[A]] =
  LazyList.unfold(Queue(tree)) { queue =>
    queue.dequeueOption.map {
      case (tree, remaining) => (tree, remaining.enqueueAll(tree.children))
    }
  }.find(tree => tree.value == value)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. It helped me review dfs and bfs. It's true that the op's code was already tail recursive, but he or she did ask about using a queue to implement bfs. Thanks again.

Comment: Why the A+ on the Tree case class? Thanks for showing the queued options. My implementation converts children into a list of Tree[A], in theory it could work for trees with more than the left right shape. It also makes the pattern matching a bit less complex. Wondering if a lazy list implementation would be "better".

Comment: @SMorrigan the `+A` is to make the **Tree** [covariant](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html). If you see in the edits, the first `bfs` implementation did something similar, I just like to keep things simple _(and IMHO, for two children, the pattern matching seems simpler)_. I am not sure what do you mean with a LazyList, where would you use it and why?

Comment: `val children: List[Tree[A]] = t.flatMap(tt => Tree.liftChildren(tt))` Right here it's creating a list of all the children of the current level, in theory if that was a LazyList would it use less memory as it scans though large rows? I agree for two children your pattern matching is easier to read.

Comment: @SMorrigan How does `t.flatMap` works? isn't `t` a **Tree**, you did not show how does it has a `flatMap` method. Anyways, maybe a **LazyList** can work, if you tree is super big, but it is still unclear to me, how it may be used in this algorithm.

Comment: I have a `t: List[Tree[A]]` mapping over each of the current level elements and getting a list of child elements. Without the flatMap it would return a `List[List[Tree[A]]` take a look at `def liftChildren[A](t: Tree[A]) = {
    List(t.Left, t.Right).flatten
  }` this flatten removes the None options.

Comment: @SMorrigan oh right, I was confused by the name. Yeah, you can built a **LazyList** that starts with the original tree, and it grows by calling the children of the elements _(either by bfs or dfs)_. And then, you can just call a simple `find` over it. That probably would be a very elegant and efficient way, if you have many elements. Let me play a bit with it and update the answer.

Comment: @SMorrigan Added to the answer.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for extending the implementation. I started thinking of tree levels as just lists of tree siblings, which lead to the whole list / lazy list approach.

Comment: @SMorrigan Yeah, your reasoning its correct. At the end, both approaches are equivalent. They both create a **Stack** / **Queue** _(dfs / bfs)_ and keep taking out items, until the target is found. Also, both are lazy in the construction, only adding more elements as required.